# Можно ли задать модификатор доступа для элементов массива?

Tags: c#, массивы, права-доступа

У меня есть класс

```
public class Status
{
    public uint[] Direction { get; internal set; }
    public uint[] Status { get; internal set; }
}
```

Я поставил `internal set`, следовательно целиком весь массив из другой сборки изменить не получится. Но вот по отдельности каждый элемент массива можно.

И возникает вопрос, можно ли как то ограничить доступ к элементам массива?

Comment: нет. можно только воспользоваться другим типом коллекций, например [ReadOnlyCollection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?view=net-6.0) и показывать наружу ее, а не массив

Comment: @Grundy, увы, но данный вариант не подойдёт, так как массивы в самой сборке постоянно изменяются. Но все равно спасибо за ответ, теперь хоть буду знать, что это нереализуемо

Comment: не вижу связи между изменением массивов внутри и выставлением публичного неизменяемого интерфейся

Comment: @Grundy, то есть вы предлагаете ввести internal переменную, и публичное свойство IReadOnlyList, который будет возвращать эту самую переменную?

Comment: не понял, что значит _ввести internal переменную_, но добавить публичное свойство с IReadOnly - да